# Hard drive not showing up during Ubuntu install for dual boot with Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I am trying to dual boot my Windows laptop with Ubuntu. I have partitioned my hard drive as follows: 
[image]
The unallocated 100GB I allotted for Ubuntu.

I used Etcher to set up my USB with the Ubuntu .iso file. I then was able to boot my system from the flash drive. However, when I went to install Ubuntu on my laptop, the  hard drive doesn't appear, just the flash drive. 
[image]

I tried clicking "New Partition Table", but that didn't change much: 
[image]

What do I need to do to make the partition on my hard drive I create accessible so that I can install Ubuntu on my hard drive?

---

EDIT:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL             UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashf                                                        /rofs
sda    iso9660 Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS amd64
│                                2017-08-01-11-51-33-00               /cdrom
├─sda2 vfat    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS amd64
│                                398E-230F                            
└─sda1 iso9660 Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS amd64
                                 2017-08-01-11-51-33-00       


ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but
Linux says it is 512 bytes.
Ignore/Cancel?


ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5904 (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:15.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d12 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d18 (rev f1)
00:1e.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d4e (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
3a:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 24fd (rev 78)
3b:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] (rev a2)



ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -C storage
  *-usb:0                 
       description: Mass storage device
       product: Cruzer Fit
       vendor: SanDisk
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@1:3
       logical name: scsi8
       version: 1.00
       serial: 4C530202001107123400
       capabilities: usb-2.10 scsi emulated scsi-host
       configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=224mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-storage
       description: RAID bus controller
       product: 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 17
       bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
       version: 21
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: storage msix pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:93190000-93197fff memory:9319c000-9319c0ff ioport:4080(size=8) ioport:4088(size=4) ioport:4060(size=32) memory:93100000-9317ffff
```

Comment: Be sure you are installing both os's in the same mode (EFI vs Legacy)

Comment: @ravery just checked, I have been booting in the same mode.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Done, see edits above.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Done.

Comment: You missed the `storage` in `sudo lshw -C storage`. But I think I can already see the issue: the storage controller is in RAID mode which appears to be unsupported in Ubuntu (fake-RAIDs often are in Linux). You need to set it to AHCI mode which will likely require you to format the entire drive.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Do I have to reformat the entire drive or can I just format the partition?

Comment: The entire drive or drives, however many are connected to the storage controller in RAID mode.